# Start Failed: Internal Error when starting Android Studio on ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu

I am starting Android Studio for the first time after unzipping the file that I downloaded from the [Android website](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) by calling  ./studio.sh in the android-studio/bin directory. I'm getting the following error:

```
    Start Failed: Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:218)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:36)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

I'm running java version 1.8.0_121

Comment: Just to be sure, have you add the Java path?

Answer (score 1):

You might have extracted and tried executing the `studio.sh` script before setting up `jdk`.

You can try to fix the problem like this:

After installing `jdk` delete the extracted android studio files, unzip them again and then execute `studio.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

The errors were caused by antivirus software (in this case Avast). After uninstalling it I was able to normally install and start Android Studio. this solved the problem.

the answer is took from here..

[Android Studio Start Failed - ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317818/android-studio-start-failed-classnotfoundexception-com-intellij-ide-plugins-p)

Comment: I don't have an antivirus software running on the ubuntu machine.

Comment: @Amitai well i think i found the error. 

You should just use JDK 1.7. There are some features in JDK 8 that are not yet supported. just install 1.7 and see again. definitely it will work. Because its worked for me.